# Different row counts for columns

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'd like to create a table in Word 2007, having X columns, and for the first column, 5 rows spanned across the whole table, followed by every other column having 17 rows. Merging isn't available for me when I highlight 13 rows to merge into 1 row (for the first column, a total of 5 rows ~ 4 rows + 1 merged row).

The first column has a text of "#1" which spans 4 rows, followed by the next column having 4 rows with text "Clean Face Bowl", "Clean Counter", "Toilet Bowl", and "Clean Glass".

Comment: Can you post a diagram or something that shows what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am confused, can you include a line drawing?

Comment: Was your issue ever resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] To match the image.

You should:

1. Click into the second cell in the first column.
2. Hold down shift and hit the down arrow to select the second and following cells.
3. Right click on the highlighted area and choose Merge Cells.

That will create the first merged area, the others follow similarly to the above.

Comment: Im not really understanding what you are saying. I updated the post with a picture of what Id like to accomplish. Thanks for the help.